# How to change or add a new item in explorer 'Other Places'?

Tags: windows-xp, performance

How to add an item here or change one of them: [image: link text]

Answer (score 0):

That's [not possible](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/34873-45-customize-other-places-list-explorer-window)

> Unfortunately, the Common Tasks pane cannot be customized.